# How to write joins in ONE to ONE relation using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two classes :
1) LAPTOP
2)STUDENT

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAPTOP")
public class Laptop {

    @Id
    private int lid;
    private String lname;

    public int getLid() {
        return lid;
    }
    public void setLid(int lid) {
        this.lid = lid;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int rollno;
    private String name;
    private int marks;

    @OneToOne
    private Laptop laptop;

    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    public Laptop getLaptop() {
        return laptop;
    }
    public void setLaptop(Laptop laptop) {
        this.laptop = laptop;
    }


}
```

How can I use joins using criteria on these tables. 
For ex : How to write this query using criteria :

select STUDENT.rollno , STUDENT.name from STUDENT inner join LAPTOP on STUDENT.laptop_lid = LAPTOP.lid;

Please give me the explanation along with the correct form of writing the criteria.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need `join` (in this query) if you don't do anything with the fields of the other table?

Comment: I need to test it how can I write the same query in hibernate

Comment: Did you find the solution? Do you need any more help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is not need for `join` in the question query, because you don't do anything with the fields of the other table. Assuming you also want to get the name of the laptop in the query, so that the `join` makes sense, you just have to define an alias:

```
// In DAO class:
public List<Object[]> findAllStudentsWithLaptop() {
    return DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class)
            .createAlias("laptop", "l")
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("rollno"))
                    .add(Projections.property("name"))
                    .add(Projections.property("l.lname")))
            .getExecutableCriteria(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()).list();
}
```

Or, if you want to get all the students with a specific laptop name:

```
// In DAO class:
public List<Object[]> findAllStudentsWithLaptop(String laptopName) {
    return DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class)
            .createAlias("laptop", "l")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("l.lname", laptopName))
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("rollno"))
                    .add(Projections.property("name")))
            .getExecutableCriteria(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()).list();
}
```

Note that (based on the only tag of the question: *hibernate*) this answer covers the legacy Hibernate `org.hibernate.Criteria` API, which now [should be considered deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-criteria).

For more information about the JPA APIs for declaring type-safe criteria queries, see [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria).